# how to concatenate the array elements and store them in a field in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am using PHP Codeigniter for a project i need to concatenate  multiple fields and make a new field called key which should be stored in same table. For eg if i insert name:jack country:USA code:+691 then my code should dynamically store JACK-USA-691 into the key field of my table. I have a base model which performs my CRUD operations. below is my controller code to get a new user(reseller) and also the model from where i get a new user(reseller):

Controller:

```
public function edit ($id = NULL)
{
    // Fetch a user or set a new one
    if ($id) {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get($id);
        count($this->data['user']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'User could not be found';
    }
    else {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get_new();
    }

    // Set up the form
    $rules = $this->reseller_m->rules_admin;
    $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    // Process the form
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {



$data = $this->reseller_m->array_from_post(array('sip_username','sip_password','key','allocation_block','name','email','password','phone','balance','user_num','address','country','created','modified','status'));


        $data['password'] = $this->reseller_m->hash($data['password']);

        $values=array($this->input->post('name'),$this->input->post('country'),$this->input->post('name'));

        $key=implode('-',$values);

        $this->db->insert('reseller',$key);



        $key=$this->reseller_m->save($data, $id);

        for($i=1; $i<=$data['user_num'];$i++)
            {
            $userdata=array('key'=>$key);
        // here users is taken name of user table with retailer_id is field
            $this->user_m->save($userdata,$id);
             }



        redirect('admin/reseller');
    }

    // Load the view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/reseller/edit';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

the model:

```
public function get_new(){
    $user = new stdClass();

//          $user->id = '';
    $user->sip_username='';
    $user->sip_password='';
    $user->key='';
    $user->allocation_block='';
    $user->name='';
    $user->email = '';      
    $user->password = '';
    $user->phone=''; 
    $user->user_num=''; 
    $user->address = '';
    $user->status = '';
    $user->country=''; 
    $user->created = '';
    $user->modified  = '';
    $user->balance = '';
    return $user;
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);

}
```

One solution that i thing is create a user the get its id and update it by concatenating the fields. i also find it right but how to concatenate elements of array ? and how to do this dynamically? Please help me with my code! Can i store the concatenated string in my database dynamically?

Comment: sounds like homework.  implode( (array)$object,'-');

Comment: yeah but can i insert this in my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `implode()` to concat as follows

```
$values=array($this->input->post('name'),$this->input->post('country'),$this->input->post('name'));
$key=implode('-',$value);

//output will be name-country-code
```

Comment: while inserting i got error Unknown column 'jack-USA-jack' in 'field list' so its taking the values to be inserted as column name

Comment: $values=array($this->input->post('name'),$this->input->post('country'),$this->input->post('name'));
   
   $key=implode('-',$values);

   $this->db->insert('reseller',$key);

Comment: i did the above and got this :(

Comment: how to insert the values in table?

Comment: i am updating in the question please check it

Comment: i have updated the question code. please check it in controller.

Comment: i want the concatenated string to be stored in key field of my table

Comment: `$this->db->insert('reseller',array('field_name'=>$key));` you missed the field name.

Comment: thats worked as charm but it affects my save function please check my code it also saves other information in database along with the key so now only key is stored and not the other information

Comment: now only my key get stored in the database and not all the fields i want to store both the key and other fields

Comment: so my current code inserts two records in database first stores all the fields in  my database and keeps the key null , while the other stores on key in second records and keep other null

Comment: i have managed to solve this bug but replacing it with $this->db->update(); but it updates all the records in database so changes the key in all columns

Comment: how to update only the current id instead of all the records

Comment: why you are inserting it two times implode data before insert first record and then add key in first inser

Comment: i dont know why but it only inserts my key in database if i write it two times otherwise returns NULL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86692/discussion-between-rajan-and-vinie).